# how to fix the button so that they don't scroll with contents

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

how to fix the buttons so that it will not scroll with  the contents.
Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/LegZv/1/

```
$(document).on('click', '.search_h', function() {

   $("#searchbar").toggle("slow");
});
```

I used css :

```
position :relative 
position :fixed
```

But it is not working

when I add that div inside the header div text (content ) come above the div.:(

First click the button it show button which scroll with the content.

Comment: It doesn't scroll for me.

Comment: I already do like that ..you can check my fiddle

Comment: Since you tagged this with `jquery-mobile` I’m assuming you’re testing this in a mobile browser? Most of these do not support `position:fixed`, for the simple reason that it would to often lead to big elements making everything else totally unreachable on small screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Css property  top. on button click .Take variable and use that.

```
  $('#realTimeContents').css('top','45px')
$("#searchbar").show("slow");


    $('#realTimeContents').css('top','0px')
     $("#searchbar").hide("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
```

In your HTML you have the code above. Simply remove it, then it will not scroll down along the content.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LegZv/8/)**

Answer (score -1):

Are you putting content and button on same place means put in different div .
so you can set position:fixed for button.

Comment: set for content property position:relative;